# "was acquainted with" or "have acquainted with"?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

I can not decide which one is correct or more accurate for using.

> I *have* acquainted with structure of remote control in primary school.
>   I *was* acquainted with structure of remote control in primary school.

I prefer the second one but is it correct to use perfect tense here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the present perfect when the time phrase in the clause excludes the present.

In your case, on a semantic level, speaking from a point in time where you are no longer in primary school, but in high school or university, the phrase **in primary school** refers to your past, excluding the present.

But if a student in primary school wins a Nobel Prize for inventing a new kind of chalk that erases itself:

> I have won the Nobel Prize, and I **have won** it in primary school.

In this particular speaker's context, **in primary school** does not exclude the present, and the sentence is grammatical.

Comment: While I agree with your comments, I think "have" can't fundamentally be used in the first sentence, irrespective of temporal context, because "acquainted" is being used as an adjective here.

Comment: @uronav: It wasn't perfectly clear to me *what* OP wanted to say; it seemed possible that it was something like "have become | became acquainted" in which case the tense of the verb would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are using *acquainted* [as an adjective](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acquainted) here. You need a structure like this:

> [subject] [verb: to be] acquainted with [object]
>
> For example: I am acquainted with electronics.

This makes your first sentence incorrect because you are using "to have" instead of "to be". If you want to use "to have", you need to replace the adjective with a noun, as in:

> I have [acquaintance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acquaintance) with electronics.

This sentence is syntactically correct but "have acquaintance" is not widely used.